# XMPP chat infrastructure recommendations

Tags: ionic-framework, xmpp, chat, ejabberd, openfire

There is a chat project I plan to develop and currently stuck while deciding, which XMPP server and client to use.
Front-end will be implemented using [Ionic 3+ framework](https://ionicframework.com/) (fixed requirement).

Main features:

- private chat capability (1 on 1)
- group chat capability (and ability to add users to existing chat)
- online status visibility
- offline message delivery (online user sends a message to offline user, and the offline user gets it after going online, etc)
- full-time server-side chat history storage

I need to select:

- a client library which is convenient to implement with Ionic 3+
- a server which enables all the above requirements

Also, the chat messages should cross the network with at least some kind of encryption.

Currently, I have been playing with these server options:

- [eJabberd](https://www.ejabberd.im/) - most people recommend this option, but for me, a person, who is newbie at XMPP stuff, it looks like there will be quite a lot of hassle with configuration
- [openFire](https://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/openfire/) - easy to setup and use, but it uses Java VM, and some people argue, that it has problems with performance and memory management.

I also stumbled upon [AstraChat](http://www.astrachat.com/) - a commercial product, that looks similar to what I need - however, with fixed implementation of it's own public apps - no way to use it's code base.

As of front-end - I have only tried running the [Ionic 1 tutorial](http://www.arjunsk.com/html5/part-2-ionic-xmpp-chat-client-using-strophe-js/) locally using [Strophe.js](https://github.com/strophe/strophejs) as the client in the front-end. Since I am developing the app with Ionic 3+ (TypeSript), it would be awesome to use some newer and TS compatible library - however, it is just a wish, not a requirement. :)

Maybe there are some better and more convenient non-XMPP implementations for this concept. Any thoughts are welcome!

Comment: For "at least some kind of encryption" just use HTTPS, that encrypts the data during transit. You can up that by adding client certificate pinning. But there will be a real security problem with storing messages on your server for offline chat. Group chat adds more security issues as does authentication the users one to another. For a secure system look at [Signal](https://signal.org/docs/) by [Open Whisper Systems](https://signal.org), it is open source. But still the security aspect is demanding.

Comment: @zaph, thank you for the suggestions!

Answer (score 3):

1. eJabbered is very complex decision for your application.
2. openFire is also very complex and requires JVM

For your apllication I advise Prosody. It is simple and lightweight desicion.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_XMPP_server_software

But please think twice about using chat on XMPP protocol. This protocol is very difficult to learn and it has a variety of extensions(e. g. XEP) and you will be confused about documentation.

Alternative https://github.com/actorapp/actor-platform
but documentation is obsolete.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. However, after many discussions, including your answer, we decided to use eJabberd. Currently I am using Strophe.js in the client, which is not very convenient to use with Ionic 2+. Maybe you have any recommendations on what client library to use for this platform?

Comment: Actually, I did not notice any proper alternative to Strophe.js